# Initial value of primitive data-types

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() :
        mFirst()
    {
    }

    int mFirst;
    int mSecond;
};


int main()
{
    MyClass mc;
    std::cout << "mc.mFirst: " << mc.mFirst << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mc.mSecond: " << mc.mSecond << std::endl;

    int a;
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the expected output of this program?

I would think only `MyClass.mFirst` will be initialized to zero. However GCC initializes them all to zero, even with optimizations enabled:

```
$ g++ -o test -O3 main.cpp
$ ./test
mc.mFirst: 0
mc.mSecond: 0
a: 0
```

I'd like to know:

1. How is each value initialized according to the C++ standard?
2. Why does GCC initialize them all to zero?

#### Update

According to Erik the values are zero because my stack happens to contain zeroes. I tried forcing the stack to be non-zero using this construct:

```
int main()
{
    // Fill the stack with non-zeroes
    {
        int a[100];
        memset(a, !0, sizeof(a));
    }
    MyClass mc;
    std::cout << "mc.mFirst: " << mc.mFirst << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mc.mSecond: " << mc.mSecond << std::endl;

    int a;
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the output stays the same:

```
mc.mFirst: 0
mc.mSecond: 0
a: 0
```

Can anyone explain why?

#### Update 2

Ok I figured it out. GCC was probably optimizing away unused variables.

This application shows the expected behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() : mFirst() { }

    MyClass(int inFirst, int inSecond) : mFirst(inFirst), mSecond(inSecond) { }

    int mFirst;
    int mSecond;
};


int main()
{
    // Fill the stack with non-zeroes
    // Use volatile to prevent GCC optimizations.
    {
        volatile MyClass mc(1, 2);
        volatile int a = 3;
    }

    {
        volatile MyClass mc;
        volatile int a;

        std::cout << "mc.mFirst: " << mc.mFirst << std::endl;
        std::cout << "mc.mSecond: " << mc.mSecond << std::endl;
        std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -o test main.cpp
$ ./test 
mc.mFirst: 0
mc.mSecond: 2
a: 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're (EDIT: With "They" i refer to mSecond and a which are not explicitly initialized)  not initialized. Your stack happens to contain 0's so that's the values you get.

8.5/9:

> If no initializer is specified for an
>   object, and the object is of (possibly
>   cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or
>   array thereof), the object shall be
>   default-initialized; if the object is
>   of const-qualified type, the
>   underlying class type shall have a
>   user-declared default constructor.
>   Otherwise, if no initializer is
>   specified for a nonstatic object, the
>   object and its subobjects, if any,
>   have an indeterminate initial
>   value; if the object or any of its
>   subobjects are of const-qualified
>   type, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Isn't `mFirst` initialized to zero because it is explicitly initialized to default in the initilizerlist of the constructor?

Comment: @Space: Edited and clarified "They" :)

Answer (score 1):

They are classified as 'undefined' meaning whatever the compiler decides or whatever was in memory at that location at the time of creation. Basically, leaving them uninitialised is leaving it up to chance and you should initialise them. The only reason for not initialising members of a struct that I can think of is if you have a very, very large array and don't want to be calling a constructor many times.